# How to specify Maven settings.xml for Kotlin DSL project in TeamCity

Tags: maven, teamcity, kotlin-dsl, maven-settings

So you can have `settings.xml` for Maven projects in TeamCity, `Administration -> Project -> Maven Settings`.

You can also store project configuration as Kotlin DSL, which is basically a Maven project stored under `.teamcity` in VCSROOT. It may even use external libraries as dependencies.

However, this Maven project will not use any `settings.xml` described above, so it can't go into HTTP auth-protected internal Maven repositories. Is there a way to specify `settings.xml` file for Kotlin DSL configuration project? Is it possible to have that file alongside pom.xml maybe? In this case, will it pick up Tokens from corresponding TeamCity tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later on I have stumbled upon [TW-53584](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-53584): The settings file needs to be named `mavenSettingsDsl.xml` and placed in `<Root project>`'s Maven Settings. It will be picked up and used.

Comment: This is also document here now: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/kotlin-dsl.html#Ability+to+Use+External+Libraries